# error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'UMPermissionsInterface.UMPermissionsInterface':

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to integrate a 3rd party library (voxeet apis) into my existed expo project. I am new to IOS and having really hard time debugging the issues. Below is the error I am getting. How can I fix it?

```
In file included from /Users/ravichandra/proj/live-consumer-mobile/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/UMPermissionsInterface/UMPermissionsInterface-umbrella.h:13:
/Users/ravichandra/proj/live-consumer-mobile/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios/UMPermissionsInterface/UMPermissionsInterface.h:4:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'UMPermissionsInterface.UMPermissionsInterface': '/Users/ravichandra/proj/live-consumer-mobile/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
        ^
```

Not sure what it means and how to fix the same. Any pointers. A part of the pod file is as follows

```
target 'localliveconsumermobile' do
  use_unimodules!
  use_modular_headers!
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. No idea how to fix it.